# Conditional Joins in Snowflake Stored procedure

Tags: sql, join, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I have to build a query which says:

join table B with table C only when table_A.column1 =table_B.column2
and if table_B and table_C produce some rows then join table_C with table_D

I found that this can be done via stored procedure.

Can anyone suggest how we can  execute conditional joins in the snowflake stored procedure

Comment: Hi  one way could be use Dynamic SQL and check if the table_A.column1 =table_B.column2 and if table_B and table_C produce some rows then do the JOIN further and execute that SQL.   What is it you want to return from the  Procedure, are you returning some data ?

Comment: The way this is described, it comes across as an inner join across all the tables - which I don't think is what you are looking for ... can you provide the code for the stored procedure (from whatever legacy DB you may be using) that shows your logic?

Comment: Conditional joins don't necessary need a stored procedure. It's hard to tell what the solution would like without some sample data, code, and output